# How do I have two different pythons at the same place

Tags: python, macos

Why does the same executable file report two different versions depending on the user/superuser status?

```
host:tmp$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
host:tmp drf$ sudo bash
bash-3.2# /usr/bin/python
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Mar  9 2014, 22:16:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
bash-3.2# ls -la /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  58608 May 15 17:32 /usr/bin/python

bash-3.2# file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/python (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
```

Comment: 58k is way too small for that to be the actual interpreter. Try viewing it.... I'll bet it's a script which executes some python version, given some environment variable.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a binary executable.  I modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/python` in Mac OSX is a proxy program that selects between different versions of python based on environment variables.  The [python(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/python.1.html) manual page describes this in some detail.  In short, the python interpreter version can be selected by:

1. defining the `VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION` environment variable to a system python version *or*
2. setting the `Version` property of the `com.apple.versioner.python` preference using **defaults write**

In either case, it will only select from the interpreters in */System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions*.